# Run-time error '9': Index outside the valid area

Tags: vba, excel

I got an error message when I run the macros. Also the coding is attached. Please any one help on this. Debug in the line `totDay = splittedday(1)`

```
Sub ChartWorking()
Dim PlanDayAddress As String
Dim splittedAddr1 As Variant, splittedday As Variant
Dim lastrow As Long, lastcol As Long, plannedDayRow As Long
Dim FirstDayCol As Long, checkingrow As Long
Dim Daystring As String, PlotAnchor As String
Dim i As Long, Loop1 As Long
Dim locallastAddr As String

PlotAnchor = "Planned Day"

clearplotarea

Range("CalculatedColumns").Columns.Hidden = False

    PlanDayAddress = "$C$4"
    splittedAddr1 = Split(PlanDayAddress, "$")
    plannedDayRow = ActiveSheet.Range(PlanDayAddress).Row
    plannedDayCol = ActiveSheet.Range(PlanDayAddress).Column

    'Find Number of Days
    lastrow = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, plannedDayCol).End(xlUp).Row

    ' to skip all if day planner is not populated with data
    If plannedDayRow = lastrow Then
        Range("CalculatedColumns").Columns.Hidden = True
        Exit Sub
    End If

    Daystring = Cells(lastrow, plannedDayCol).Value
    splittedday = Split(Daystring, " ")
    totDay = splittedday(1)

Range("CalculatedColumns").Columns.Hidden = True
```

Comment: My guess is Daystring isn't the expected value (did you clear out a cell by chance?).  Again, just a guess, but I suspect it's looking for a date in format "MM dd yyyy" based on your code.

Comment: If `Daystring` does not contain any spaces, you will only have one entry in `splittedday` (i.e. `splittedday(0)`) and therefore `splittedday(1)` will give a "subscript out of range" error.  So check the value that `DayString` contains.

Comment: ^^ This. Use `Debug.Print` or Breakpoints. [How to debug VBA code](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/DebuggingVBA.aspx)

Comment: [VBA Docs, error 9](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/vba/8917/vba-run-time-errors/27748/run-time-error-9-subscript-out-of-range#t=201705300830026211205)